# Android Studio Problem with instalation app on Smartphon

Tags: android-studio, installation

I have a problem with instalation my app on smartphon. When I run it on virtual device evrythinkg is ok, but when i try to use it on my mobile phone i got this log. Someone knows what's wrong? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBHhK.jpg)

When I tried with basic app, results were the same.. My phon : Samsung galaxy J7

Comment: It says your MainmenuActivity doesn't exist, try invalidating cache/restart or clean then rebuild project

Comment: Unfortunatly it still doesn't work. The same log ;/

Comment: did you declare it at androidmanifest?

Comment: I think so. Sorry
i am very beginner in android dev so i give a photo below.

Comment: Can you check your storage space? I think you don't have enough space on your mobile.